# python structure for scripts with dependencies?

Tags: python, package, directory-structure

I have a python project setup like the following:

```
monitoring
|\__helper_functions
|        - init.py
|        - helpers.py
|
|\__docs
|
|\__monitoring_scripts
|
|\__CLI_interfacing_scripts
|
 \__event_handling_scripts
```

Basically there are some python scripts and some helper files. I intend these to be executables called by another program. The scripts all reference the helper functions. But, because they are both in subdirectories separate from the root folder I'm not sure how to reference them. In PyCharm every subdirectory has its own `__init__.py` but I'm not sure that is correct.

I could move all the scripts in the root directory and make an init.py in both the helper and the root directory, then just `import scripts.what_i_need` but I don't like not having them organized by purpose. The only reason I want to do that is just so that it can be broken up in the future.

I want the usage of this basically to be that someone can download this folder, and configure the interfacing application to point to it and that application executes what it needs to from this folder.

EDIT: Ideally I want to, in each individual script, be able to write

`import x`

and it would automatically reference the helper folder

Comment: Can you not simply do `import helper_functions.helpers` or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I would highly recommend this talk to answer your questions: [David Beazley - Modules and Packages: Live and Let Die! - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0). Slides are available in the video description.

Comment: @MattMS I can do that but that makes multiple references really annoying to navigate. I want to make sure that the person reading this code after me can easily navigate it and undertand it

Comment: I would recommend against something that would import all the subfolders into the current scope. That would make it harder to track objects to their source. Like how `from a import *` is a bad idea.

Comment: Importing local modules using `import x` is broken. You should always try to arrange things so that the scripts can do `from mypackage import x`. This implies that the scripts belong in the same directory as the package. Otherwise, you will be forced to do `sys.path` manipulations to get things to work properly.

Comment: noted, thank you guys. so i should turn the helper into a package and do `from helper_functions import x` whenever I need it in each of the scripts. if each type of script is in a different subdir and the helper functions are also a subdir on the same level, then does that mean I need to make a package in the root directory? on what level does the python know to search within a certain directory for packages?

Comment: @frei. The directory of the executed script is automatically inserted at the beginning of `sys.path`. So if the script and the package are in the same directory, `from pkg import x` is guaranteed to work in both the script and in any other module within the package itself. Your problems are caused by having the scripts in separate directories. If they were all in the `monitoring` directory, it would simplify everything. Maybe you should think about namespacing the scripts using prefixes - e.g. `mon_script.py`, `cli_script.py`, etc - instead of using sub-directories?

Comment: that sounds like a good idea @ekhumuro - I thought I could divide them for functionality by putting them in folders but name spacing them works too.